# substring to get image no

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using sub-string function i want to get image no. from string ,

i am applying sub-string to below property .this return 3 at the end in chrome but in mozilla it is not working properly.

**Problem :**
 above " -->" after this i have written chrome values , in mozilla on third step i get .jpg instead of 3.jpg

```
alert("obj.back is "+obj.style.backgroundImage);-->url(http://localhost/final.21/img/img3.jpg);
    origImg = obj.style.backgroundImage.split(")")[0];
    alert('origImg is'+origImg);  -->>url(http://localhost/final.21/img/img3.jpg
    alert('after length '+origImg.substring(origImg.length-5)); -->3.jpg
    origImg = origImg.substring(origImg.length-5).split(".")[0];
    alert('origImg is'+origImg);  --> 3
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong in Firefox?

Comment: @ChenAsraf above " -->"  after this i have written chrome values , in mozilla on third step i get .jpg instead of 3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this also

```
var myUrl = 'http://localhost/final.21/img/img3.jpg';
alert(myUrl.substr(myUrl.length - 5).slice(0, -4));
```

Answer (score 1):

later i get to know that with `"obj.style.backgroundImage"` Property , In Mozilla i was getting `url("/final.21/img/img3.jpg");`  where in chrome i am getting `url(/final.21/img/img3.jpg);` ... so i changed my substring method

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a more readable solution using RegEx. Your solution is quite static and if something changes (i.e. you have something like img33.jpg) it will break. Additionally, as I already mention, I would say it is more readable as it actually expresses what you are trying to do.

```
var url = "http://localhost/final.21/img/img3.jpg)";
origImg = url.match("img([0-9]+).jpg");
alert('origImg is '+origImg[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution using RegEx

```
var str = "http://localhost/final.21/img/img3.jpg";
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
alert(str.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/drF8y/

Comment: Imho this is the least elegant solution proposed here. One should either go for the solution proposed by Anna.P using pure substring functionality or go for pure Regex like my solution. This is a mixup of both and it is neither fast nor easily readable.

Comment: @dirkk this was suitable solution for me what if i don't have img1.jpg instead if i have  image 40.jpg  ???  i find drikk answer helpful

Comment: @simmisimmi You can do this with pure regex as well. You didn't state in your question what could be the possible formats for this filename. You could do also a simple `([0-9]+).jpg`, which would match image 40.jpg as well.